# Make a union of polygons in GeoPandas, or Shapely (into a single geometry)

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to find the union of two polygons in GeoPandas and output a single geometry that encompasses points from both polygons as its vertices.  The `geopandas.overlay` function gives me polygons for each individual union but I would like a single polygon.

For context, I'm using this to combine two administrative areas together into a single area (i.e. include a town district within a country).

The following example is from the geopandas website and illustrates what I'd like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                         Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])

polys2 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)]),
                         Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])])

df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys1, 'df1':[1,2]})
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys2, 'df2':[1,2]})

res_union = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='union')
res_union.plot()
```

[image: res_union.png]

None of the output geometries are what I was expected, which is the following:

```
poly_union = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (1,2), (1,3), \
    (2,3), (2,4), (3, 4), (3, 5), (5, 5), (5, 3), (4, 3), (4, 2), \
    (3,2), (3,1), (2, 1), (2, 0), (0, 0)])])

poly_union.plot(color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

[image: union.png]

Firstly, how do I output the above polygon (`poly_union`) from the input polygons (`df1`, `df2`) using GeoPandas or shapely?

Secondly, what is the correct nomenclature associated with the geometry (`poly_union`) that I'm trying to find?  I would call it a 'union' but every example I find that refers to 'unions' does not output this geometry.

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325030/merging-two-geojson-polygons-in-python) example does not seem to output a single polygon either:

```
poly1 = df1['geometry']; poly2 = df2['geometry']
mergedpoly = poly1.union(poly2)
mergedpoly.plot()
```

[image: merged_poly.png]

Comment: For a record, in 2020, with geopandas v 0.8.1, all the `overlay` operations are not changed (as I observed since v 0.6.1).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**Note: `cascaded_union` mentioned in the answer below is superceded by `unary_union` if GEOS 3.2+ is used - this allows unions on different geometry types, not only polygons. To check your version,**

```
>>> shapely.geos.geos_version
(3, 5, 1)
```

---

From the question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151254/using-cascaded-union-to-combine-shapes), it seems this is called a [`cascaded_union` within `shapely`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union):

```
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
polygons = [poly1[0], poly1[1], poly2[0], poly2[1]]
boundary = gpd.GeoSeries(cascaded_union(polygons))
boundary.plot(color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

[image: union]

Comment: ```cascaded_union```  is superseded by ```shapely.ops.unary_union()``` as mentioned [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union). It works on different geometry types (not only polygons)

Comment: I get an error: `TopologyException: side location conflict at 5.4185235483127627 58.392789795412952`.

Answer (score 23):

If you prefer Geopandas over Shapely you might consider dissolve and use a column with a constant value for all entries:
http://geopandas.org/aggregation_with_dissolve.html

Answer (score 17):

@Rutger Hofste's answer worked best for me as well. In case your polygons are lacking of a column with a constant value, just simply create one by

`gdf['new_column'] = 0
gdf_new = gdf.dissolve(by='new_column')`

Comment: If you want to unpack multi geoms afterwards, you can try 
`gdf_new = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in gdf_new.geometry.iloc[0].geoms])`