# How to turn a PNG into a shapefile without black lines

Tags: opencv, shapefile, shapely

I have a PNG image where each color is a type of landcoverage. I go and check all of these colours and extract it's contours with cv2.

```
    for color in target_colors:
        mask = cv2.inRange(input_image, color, color)

        # Find contours in the mask
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Then I get all these contours turn each into points and then those points into a geometry.

```
points = [
                (
                    round((point[0][0] * np.abs(x_resolution)) + extent.left, 4),
                    round((point[0][1] * np.abs(y_resolution)) + extent.bottom, 4),
                )
                for point in contours
            ]

            if len(points) >= 4:
                polygon = Polygon(points)
                polygon = polygon.buffer(0)

                gdf_temp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=[polygon], crs=crs)
```

And I do this for each different colour.

After I am done with this I will have several shapefiles which all seem normal. However I have to merge these shapefiles into one.

For this I use this code:

```
gdf_original = gpd.read_file(f"{path_list[0]}/SHP.shp")


    for i in range(1, len(path_list)):
        gdf_next = gpd.read_file(f"{path_list[i]}/SHP.shp")


        gdf_original = gpd.pd.concat(
            [gdf_original, gdf_next]
        )  
        gdf_original["geometry"] = gdf_original["geometry"].buffer(0)


    gdf_original['geometry'] = gdf_original['geometry'].simplify(tolerance=0.001, preserve_topology=True)


        gdf_original.to_file(f"{result_place}/output.shp")
```

When I am done I can clearly see the connections between the smaller shapefiles because there is a black line along each of them.

What can I do to remove these lines from the resulting shapefile?

I already tried differnet contour finding methodes.

Comment: Which line do you think is supposed to merge the geometries? I don't see any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385782/make-a-union-of-polygons-in-geopandas-or-shapely-into-a-single-geometry